# How do I make my title bar take up the intended space in CSS?

Tags: css, spacing

**Hello!**
I'm having problems with my title bar not taking up the intended space. Here's a diagram:
[Diagram of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHfhb.png)
The area I highlighted in red is where I want my title bar to be (Next to the existing buttons) but my title bar instead moves to the next line.
Here's the code:

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
div.titlebar{
    background-color: rgb(226, 147, 0);
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
}
div.titlebutton{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.titlebutton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(226, 147, 0);
}
#editor{
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 45px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div#rest {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titlebar">Text Editor</div><div class="titlebutton" id="save">Save</div><div class="titlebutton" id="load">Load</div><div id="rest"></div>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <script src="text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Attempts to fix

> ! (Please keep in mind that I'm a CSS beginner)
> I tried using `width:100%;` along with `display:inline-block;` to make it go next to the buttons. I'm not familiar with other ways to do it, so that's the only way I tried aside from `display:inline;`, that ended up breaking the whole bar.

Answer (score 0):

You've made this quite hard for yourself by not including a wrapper element for the titlebar. The layout you're going for is very flexbox and so naturally you'd want a flexbox parent for the items inside the titlebar:

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
div.titlebar-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(226, 147, 0);
}
div.titlebar{
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
}
div.titlebutton{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.titlebutton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(226, 147, 0);
}
#editor{
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 45px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titlebar-wrapper">
      <div class="titlebar">Text Editor</div><div class="titlebutton" id="save">Save</div><div class="titlebutton" id="load">Load</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <script src="text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This also allows you to get rid of the `<div id="rest">`, by simply giving the parent the appropriate `background-color`.

### Edit

Here's one that retains the margins by putting the `background-color` on the flex children (as you essentially already had) and changing the `#rest`'s width for a `flex: 1` to get it to fill the remaining space (replacing the `width: 100%`).

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
div.titlebar-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
div.titlebar{
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 147, 0);
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
}
div.titlebutton{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.titlebutton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(226, 147, 0);
}
#editor{
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 45px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#rest {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titlebar-wrapper">
      <div class="titlebar">Text Editor</div><div class="titlebutton" id="save">Save</div><div class="titlebutton" id="load">Load</div><div id="rest"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <script src="text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great solution, but i want it to be as if it was a seperate "button" per se (2px left margin), instead of it taking up the entirety of the viewport's width. Otherwise, great solution!

Comment: You can leave `#rest` in there, if you like; or simply put the margin on the flex container. If you must have `#rest`, as well as the margin, then you can move the background color from the parent to the children instead. I'll edit my answer to show this as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap it in a container that is block formatted and make the buttons inside inline-block, it should work as a base point. Then you could text-align on the container div to make it either left or right and all the buttons should be aligned next to each other. From there, you can apply any other styling you want to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .titlebutton{
            display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titlebar">Text Editor<div class="titlebutton" id="save">Save</div><div class="titlebutton" id="load">Load</div><div id="rest"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your code and explain how it can be implemented if applicable.